# Deleting an autocmd after it's run

Tags: autocmd

I have this function that I rarely run and it uses `matchaddpos`.  This function highlights at a set position so if I edit text, the same spot is highlighted even though the contents have shifted.  I figure the best way to solve this is to create an autocmd like this:

```
augroup headwords
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * call clearmatches()
augroup end
```

That works fine, but it seems unnecessary to have that run every time I enter insert mode.  How could I make this "self destructing".  Where if this autocmd runs one, it no longer runs on future InsertEnter's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `autocmd! headwords`.  For example,

```
augroup headwords
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * call clearmatches() | autocmd! headwords
augroup end
```